# remove bold type in latvian letter

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have surname in my text which is in latvian and letter č in html shows in bold. I tried to give css `font-weight:normal`, but it doesn't help. How can I remove boldness from that letter?

Comment: can  u show  your html  or used to font-weight:100;

Comment: I used font-weight:100 but no success

Comment: Which font do you use? Perhaps the letter is only in bold!?!

Comment: I wrote that surname just in div tag

Comment: font is brandon_grotesquelight

Comment: Most likely the font you are using does not contain a glyph for that letter, so the browser is falling back to another font which looks bolder in comparison to brandon_grotesquelight. In that case you just need to use a different font which includes the full Latvian alphabet.

Comment: nothing more except changing font family?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a font which helps to display latvian letters correctly and without any difference between letters. Here is my css for font: `font-family: "Arial Unicode MS"`

Answer (score 1):

Choose a font from [this](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/language/latvian) link, and then set the font type in your body to it.

```
<body style="font-family:*your selected font's name*;" >
    /*your code*/
    </body>
```

Or if you want to change the font only around the area where the surname needs to be displayed, use a  div tag with inline css.

```
<div style="font-family:*your selected font's name*;" >
/*your code*/
</div>
```

Just remember to choose a font that has Latvian support and goes with your design requirement.

Comment: for example I used Alegreya Regular, but this letter Č was different from other letters and was still bolder than other, I have tried also Alegreya Bold but same result - it is different from other letters.

Comment: Could be because your css may be overidden somewhere. Check in the chrome debugger

Comment: use an !important tag with the css. Might help. Hopefully only.

Comment: Unfortunately no, it doesn't help, anyways thanks much @Nisal Upendra. I found one useful font. Guess will use this one.

Comment: Great! please make sure you answer your question with it. I also do some internationalization work so it might come useful. Happy Coding!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83115/discussion-between-aidaghazaryan-and-nisal-upendra).